# Position fixed with floated element

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
 <style>
 #wrapper {
   width:100%;
   height:1000px;
   border:1px solid #000000;
 }
 #right {
   position:fixed;
   top: 10px;
   float:right;
   width:200px;
   height:100px;
   border:1px solid #000000;
 }
 </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="right"></div>
</div>

</body>    
</html>
```

How to keep the `right` element floated to the right of the wrapper while using fixed positioning?

Comment: You can't float a fixed element, it's outside the document flow so it would make no sense !

Answer (score 0):

If instead of using `float:right;` you can use `right:0px;` then this will work.
You can add/subtract pixels to get the correct location.


This is seen working here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZK42k/

Comment: the problem is that when the screen has a different resolution, these numbers will not work and the element would be displayed incorrectly..is there a way to keep the child floated sticking to the wrapper?

Comment: when a horizontal scrollbar is displayed, element will move over other elements

Comment: @MichaelSamuel As adeneo says, both float and fixed would make no sense. Can you describe what you want it to look like on the screen, without thinking in terms of positioning or floating?